# Word recommendation keyboard for Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-keyboard

You guys would have seen the word recommendation keyboards on mobile phones like gboard, swiftkey, etc. Actually most of the mobile keyboards have the predictive element.

Is there anything I can install that will provide me with word completion / next word prediction for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

using the search terms "predictive text ubuntu" I located a large number of possibly suitable applications for ubuntu.

The first three are listed here:

[Presage](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/libpresage1/)

[Dasher](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/natty/dasher/)

[Soothsayer (news/description page)](https://www.linux.com/news/predictive-text-input-soothsayer)

[Soothsayer download sourceforge link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/soothsayer/)

I cannot attest to the precision or suitability of these packages, although Soothsayer's description includes reference to the ability to customize various features of the program.